# Wordpress 404 page when using /%category%/%postname%, works when using just /%postname%

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404, permalinks

When I set my permalinks to use /%category%/%postname% i get a 404 page, but if i set it to just /%postname% it works fine.

htaccess is set to mod rewrites etc, here is a broken post example:

http://s23771.p717.sites.pressdns.com/blog/sales/amazong-will

The site only has 2 categories and 1 post created as its a test to see if the structure is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before.
Only setting mod rewrites is not enough.

I found from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17207997/4085497).
go to`/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and make following changes in default file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +ExecCGI 
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/blog/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```